# How can I fix this Polyfit error with Numpy in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

When I run any program that uses Numpy in Pycharm, it returns the following error:

```
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/0_/ry6vqn855lq0d7n4mww1fks00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2710F87A-D4CC-42F0-82D4-81D5521E1E33/d/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

This error is returned whenever I attempt to `import numpy`, also if I simply type `import numpy as np` in the python console.

I believe I may have to redownload numpy, but I don't even know how to uninstall it from Pycharm in the first place. Do you guys know whether or not I just have to reinstall Numpy, and if so, how to uninstall it from Pycharm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
pip install numpy
```

At the cmd for windows

Get cmd: win_key+r

To uninstall using in cmd:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

But main problem, I think, with python 3.9

Reinstall **to python 3.8** first.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already have numpy installed using pip like you suggested, so I'm going to try and change python interpreter to 3.8.

Comment: There are a lot of question with py3.9. I think it’s install later)

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: I'm downloading 3.8 right now! Trust me, I'll get back to you if it works. Thanks again! Fingers crossed.

Edit: It did! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I was receiving this error when I installed Pandas (which installed Numpy). After Pandas finishing I had to uninstall numpy and reinstall and this fixed it. This was on Mac OS X when using PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was running python 3.8.6, I upgraded the version of NumPy and it worked like a charm.

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```